# Checkstyle report generate graphs report

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle to generate reports using ANT. It displays report in html form. Is it possible to generate report in graphical way(like bar graph, pie chart etc). If yes please guide me how to do this? jenkins project generate graphical report https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin. Is there any plugins to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jenkins,you can add Post-build Actions in your job.Before this make sure that you've already installed the jenkins checkstyle plugin.

Change the output of the checkstyle from HTML to XML.The Jenkins Checkstyle plugin will help you parse the xml file after the job.Then you can see the graph in the job page of jenkins.